# Eclipse Debugger not able to make use of shell commands like 'ssh' or 'whoami'... Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, shell

I am trying to debug a project (Testing Framework for SDN Controllers). I didn't write the Code, I am just trying to install the Framework and understand the Code. When I start the Program, everything works fine (Web UI is accessible and I can choose a TestCase and execute it on for example ONOS 1.9 ... But then the Program gives me a NullPointerException. I want to debug the project, but my Eclipse is not getting to the NullPointerException, because somehow it can't make use of the shell-scripts that are used in the java code. For example the script 'delta-run-onos' contains:

```
  37  ssh ubuntu@10.0.3.11 "
  38  sudo update-java-alternatives --set $JDK_VERSION
  39  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
  40  export ONOS_APPS=drivers,openflow,proxyarp,mobility,fwd
  41  /home/ubuntu/onos-1.9.0/bin/onos-service clean
  42  "
```

It would give me following error:

```
/home/ben/DELTA/tools/dev/app-agent-setup/onos/delta-run-onos: line 37: ssh: command not found
```

When I execute the Project not in Eclipse, the script would work perfectly...
Is there an Eclipse Plugin or something else, that I am missing, so that ssh (and other commands) won't work?

Comment: Eclipse can't see `ssh`. Try running `which ssh` and substitute whatever it says into your script.

Comment: oh wow! that worked perfectly!!! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse can't see `ssh`.

As a quick workaround try running `which ssh` and substitute whatever it says into your script.

(answer was previously a comment)